# Is it possible to implement scipy.lfilter in c?

Tags: python, c, filter, scipy

With the help of **scipy.lfilter** i can easily bring a solution using that filter function in python but now i need to implement the filter function in C Program.
If it is possible how can i implement the same scipy.lfilter in C?
I wish to know the concept behind that **scipy.lfilter**.

Comment: It's all open source, so you could read it. Further, Python and C work together pretty well, so chances are that it's possible. Apart from that, your Q isn't really up to SO standards, because it is basically an open-ended research question. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Apologize for that, suddenly i decided to post the question without knowing this